# Cannot create lvm snapshot

Tags: lvm

I've found a proble creating a snapshot, as follows:

```
[root@centos7 ~]# vgs centos
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
  centos   3   2   0 wz--n- 9,50g 1,99g
[root@centos7 ~]# LANG=C lvcreate --size 300M --snapshot --name alfa /dev/mapper/centos-root  device-mapper: reload ioctl on  failed: Invalid argument
  Aborting. Failed to activate snapshot exception store.
[root@centos7 ~]# dmesg | tail
[   21.881931] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   22.144349] Ebtables v2.0 registered
[   22.205835] Bridge firewalling registered
[   23.694962] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vhgnet0: link is not ready
[   23.695831] e1000: vhgnet0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[   23.696502] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vhgnet0: link becomes ready
[   41.871876] device-mapper: table: 253:6: linear: dm-linear: Device lookup failed
[   41.872657] device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
[  737.566773] device-mapper: table: 253:7: linear: dm-linear: Device lookup failed
[  737.567120] device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
```

what's wrong with this?

Comment: doesn't look like you have the properly specified the volume group correctly.  It's name looks like centos to me not centos-root.

Comment: Try this instead to see if it makes a difference: `LANG=C lvcreate --size 300M --snapshot --name alfa /dev/centos/root`. Also confirm that `root` is a LV within VG `centos`. Use the command `lvs`.

Comment: It's as if some of the PV was part of a dm device, removing traces of a software raid, made the trick.